# Likelihood Ratio Test in R returning strange values when assessing linear mixed effect model

Tags: r, mixed-models, polynomial-math

I have created a model of some data which I believe will fall along a quadratic curve, I've written the full model as:

```
model <- lmer(
  DV ~ I(predictor^2) + predictor + (predictor | rand_effect),
  data = data, 
  REML=FALSE
)
```

and the comparison as:

```
modelcomp <- lmer(
  DV ~ (predictor | rand_effect),
  data = data, 
  REML=FALSE
)
```

When I use a likelihood ratio test using the anova function:

`lrt <- anova(model, modelcomp)`

I get a very high chi squared (57779.45) and a more concerning p value of exactly 0. It was my impression that p values generally couldn't be exactly 0. Why might this be? How do I correct my code so that it computes a sensible p value?

Comment: can you show more detail please?  It would be good to see `summary()` of both models as well as the `anova()` output ...

Comment: Most likely the p-value is so low that it can't be expressed as a floating point value. `pchisq(58000,df=1,lower.tail=FALSE,log.p=TRUE)/log(10)` shows that if the chi-squared statistic is correct, your p-value is approximately 10^(-12597).  Double-precision floating-point variables can't handle values less than about 10^(-308).